# Object Doesn't support this Property or Method ActiveWorkbook object VBA

Tags: excel, vba, methods, properties

I'm getting a

> "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

with the following line of code on VBA for excel

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DataU1").Sort.SortFields
```

Does anyone know what is causing this? Sort.SortFields is a property/method of ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: But you're dealing with a `Worksheet`, not a `Workbook`. What's the rest of the code?

Comment: That line of code correctly references the `SortFields` object for that sheet.  But on its own that code is not valid, you need to do something with the object.  Eg `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DataU1").Sort.SortFields.Clear`

Comment: ```ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DataU1").Sort.SortFields.Clear ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DataU1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B5:B" & lRow _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal``` Also one thing to note is I'm trying to sort by number and then there are some cells that say "Data Hole" which I want to be at the bottom.

Comment: Matt, please use the [edit] link below a question to include additional information directly into the question. Code is not readable in a comment, for one thing... Also, in order to answer someone in comments you need to "ping" them by preceding their screen name with `@`. Otherwise, there is no notification so no one who asked for information will see that you've tried to supply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had to use a different version of excel to run a macro to pull data from a server. The older version wouldn't let me use any of these class methods. The solution was to just use my 2019 version of excel and run the other macros after pulling the data.